# How to count directories in make file

Tags: if-statement, makefile, directory, gnu-make, getdirectories

I have `makefile(.mke)` on Windows and I need to count directories in a folder which start with "Install" and then `make` if clause to throw an `exception` if there are more than one directory like this.

**For example:**

```
Files: Install.1.0, Install.2.0, Install.3.0..
```

I have `$(SrcRoot)` variable and I need to count directories in this folder then make if clause that "`if (numberOfDirs > 1) throw an error.`"

In my example there would be an exception because there are 3 Install.. folders.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by *"throw an exception"* you mean abort Make with an error message, this will do it:

```
INSTALLS := $(wildcard $(SrcRoot)/Install*)

ifneq (,$(word 2,$(INSTALLS)))
$(error there are too many Install directories)
endif
```